# "Pesquisa recusada" no Registro.br

Tags: amazon-aws, dns, domínio, cpanel, whm

Estou tentando direcionar meu domínio para os nameservers que acabei de configurar na AWS Route53 da Amazon. Os mesmos funcionam corretamente, porém acredito que não estão respondendo por outros domínios além do raiz (oregionalsul.com).

Para checar a autoridade sobre determinado domínio, estou utilizando **[uma ferramenta do próprio Registro.br.](https://registro.br/cgi-bin/nicbr/dnscheck)**

[image]

### Configuração do nameserver

[image]

**Veja que tenho quatro nameservers principais:**

- ns1.oregionalsul.com
- ns2.oregionalsul.com
- ns3.oregionalsul.com
- ns4.oregionalsul.com

### Configuração do DNS do domínio tiagoboeing.com.br no WHM

**Preste atenção que este é outro domínio que não possui ligação com o raiz (oregionalsul.com)**

Para entender melhor, veja a configuração atual:

- Instância EC2 (com WHM e Cpanel instalado)
- Route53 do domínio raiz do EC2 (oregionalsul.com) - aqui é feita a configuração dos nameservers próprios.
- A conta de qualquer outro domínio é criada pelo WHM, os nameservers próprios configurados no Route53 devem responder pelo que está sendo hospedado.
- Padrão de configuração de revendas de hospedagem, porém neste caso não é para revenda.

[image]

Comment: Voce editou o DNS do registro.br? Seu DNS está apontando para e.sec.dns.br e f.sec.dns.br

Se voce for utilizar outro lugar para configurar a zona vc deve apontar no registro.br

Comment: se vc esta utilizando o Route 53 vc ja errou....quando vc cria um dominio no Route 53 ele gera 4 DNS da propria amazon. Esse DNS vc deve colocar no registro.br

Comment: Pelo q vi vc alterou seu NS e alterou os DNS da amazon para registro A apontando para dominios diferentes. Isso foge totalmente da lógica no meu entendimento. Voce deve manter os NS da amazon como registro NS mesmo e configurar no registro.br eles.

Comment: Amigo, na verdade o Route53 ele é relacionado ao domínio principal. É a forma de se hospedar domínios a um ec2 na Amazon. Tenho um servidor rodando o WHM e Cpanel e através dele crio as contas que necessito, sendo assim o Route53 faz a configuração WhiteLabel, recomendada pela própria amazon, que seriam os ns1.meudominio.com, ns2, ns3...

Comment: No caso como você citou, eu não posso utilizar os nameservers fornecidos pela amazon no route53, porque os mesmos são referentes ao domínio raiz. Dessa forma eu teria que criar uma zona hospedada para cada domínio que vou utilizar no WHM, gerando custos desnecessários e excessivos. Até tentei utilizar o NS gerado no registro.br, porém a consulta também retorna como recusada.

Comment: Esta é a documentação da Amazon que aborda sobre a recomendação de utilizar WhiteLabel, nameservers próprios: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html - Talvez não tenha ficado claro, então editei minha pergunta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Os registros A que vc fez pros ns da amazon nao servem pra nada `ns-1914.awsdns-47.co.uk A 205.251.199.122`. Eu creio que o problema está acontecendo no proprio registro.br, vc deve colocar os NS lá. ns1.oregionalsul.com e assim por diante.

Comment: Bota **TYPE** para o valor **C** nos IP's iniciados em 205.*.*.* (Só um detalhe )

Comment: Você diz isso no painel do route53 ou do WHM?

Answer (score 0):

Opa também tive esse problema de pesquisa recusada! O que eu fiz primeiro editei a zona la no registro.br e coloquei de acordo com o que tinha registrodo la no aws!
Depois migrei o DNS para usar os servidores do próprio registro.br e após permitir que eu pudesse alterar novamente o dns eu fui la no Route53 apaguei tudo e criei novamente! Com os links novos(Gerado no Route53) alterei no registro.br e funcionou normalmente!

Comment: Você descreveu sua solução para um domínio ou para domínio autoritário, comumente utilizado em revendas? Ex.: Um domínio raiz responde pelos outros "filhos". À época consegui resolver o problema, porém acabei deixando de lado AWS e migrei para outro serviço.

Answer (score 0):

Vc deve criar a zona na AWS route53 como public, se estiver como private dará este erro no registro.br.

Comment: A questão é antiga, não tenho mais como realizar testes pois acabei implementando a nuvem privada de outra forma, mas pelo que me lembro estava como privado assim. Assim que tiver a oportunidade irei testar novamente.